# Pandas to_numeric turning my series in NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to change my column Votes from an object to a float, but every time I use the to_numeric it returns NaN.

```
dados["Votes"] = pd.to_numeric(dados["Votes"],errors="coerce")

dados["Votes"]

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
995   NaN
996   NaN
997   NaN
998   NaN
999   NaN
Name: Votes, Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your input data?

Comment: Please share a sample of your `dados['Votes']`. Reason for this could be that there are many `str` type values along with `float` values in the `Votes` column.

Comment: Probably you have objects which are not convertible to float. You can replace those with zero such as dados["Votes"] = pd.to_numeric(dados["Votes"],errors="coerce").fillna(0, downcast='infer')

Comment: 0      2,295,987
1      1,584,782
2      2,260,649
3      1,107,253
4      1,614,369
         ...    
995      256,515
996      367,489
997      139,634
998       42,160
999       45,579
Name: Votes, Length: 1000, dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
dados["Votes"] = dados["Votes"].astype('Float32')
```

notice the capital **F**loat32

Comment: Whats the difference between 'float32' and 'Float32'. I couldn't reproduce different behaviour or find it in the documentation.

Comment: Well recently they added [Int64](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html#pandas.Int64Dtype) so I assumed they also added Float32 ... but maybe that is not the point ...